# Need To fill Svg Animation for a curve

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg, svg-animate

I have a curve in svg and need to fill the curve along its path on hover can anyone help?  The animation for fill should be in another color or can be the same. I tried using the animate tag but it is not effective and fills like anything. My SVG path is given below. This is my Svg code and need this path to fill as dashoffset.

```html
<svg width="210mm" height="45mm" viewBox="0 0 744.09449 159.44881">
    <path style="opacity:1;fill:#ded9d5;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:0;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1"
          d="m 18.929688,529.44141 c 1.140051,2.17164 1.739409,4.60197 1.74414,7.07226 -0.0033,2.41521 -0.575072,4.79339 -1.666016,6.92969 l 36.876954,0 c 17.101683,0 11.124297,14.78094 13.525192,34.92207 7.304679,27.32129 35.935342,38.13518 62.612922,41.73111 -1.5457,-2.42739 -4.33484,-7.94712 -4.33733,-10.8524 0.005,-3.11453 0.90166,-5.74434 2.66254,-8.27277 -23.30774,-1.1068 -29.8766,-7.34118 -39.33413,-22.29658 -4.829034,-11.35821 5.68082,-49.23338 -28.703413,-49.23338 z" transform="translate(0.5714286,1.42857)" id="path4471" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you include your animate attempt?

Comment: <defs>
      <linearGradient id="fill_anim">
       <stop offset="0" stop-color="#B6E7F3">
        <animate id="arrow_fill1" dur="1s" attributeName="offset" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1" restart="always" />
       </stop>
       <stop offset="0" stop-color="#ded9d5">
        <animate id="arrow_fill2" dur="1s" attributeName="offset" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1" />
       </stop>
      </linearGradient>
     </defs>

Comment: Please edit the question, code in comments is not readable.

Answer (score 7):

Your SVG patch code goes beyond the user `viewport`, so you can not see the curve.
I optimized your SVG code a little using - [svg-editor Peter Collingridge](https://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor)

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 width="420" height="180" viewBox="-50 540 372 80.4" >
<path id="path1" d="m18.9 529.4c1.1 2.2 1.7 4.6 1.7 7.1 0 2.4-0.6 4.8-1.7 6.9l36.9 0c17.1 0 11.1 14.8 13.5 34.9 7.3 27.3 35.9 38.1 62.6 41.7-1.5-2.4-4.3-7.9-4.3-10.9 0-3.1 0.9-5.7 2.7-8.3-23.3-1.1-29.9-7.3-39.3-22.3-4.8-11.4 5.7-49.2-28.7-49.2z"  style=" stroke:none; stroke-width:1; fill:#ded9d5; />  
</svg>
```

Your code draws a closed path, so animation with the use of the `stroke-dashoffset` attribute will draw a curve along a closed path.

The example below. The beginning of the animation is when you hover over the shape.

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 width="420" height="180" viewBox="-50 540 372 80.4" >
  
  <path id="path1" d="m18.9 529.4c1.1 2.2 1.7 4.6 1.7 7.1 0 2.4-0.6 4.8-1.7 6.9l36.9 0c17.1 0 11.1 14.8 13.5 34.9 7.3 27.3 35.9 38.1 62.6 41.7-1.5-2.4-4.3-7.9-4.3-10.9 0-3.1 0.9-5.7 2.7-8.3-23.3-1.1-29.9-7.3-39.3-22.3-4.8-11.4 5.7-49.2-28.7-49.2z"  
  style=" stroke:#4B0082; stroke-width:3; fill:#ded9d5; stroke-dasharray:571; stroke-dashoffset:571;">
  <animate id="dash" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="571;0;571" begin="path1.mouseover" restart="whenNotActive" dur="5s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
  </path>
</svg>
```

`begin="path1.mouseover"` - command to start the animation, where `path1` is the path identifier

`restart="whenNotActive"` - to prevent re-animation

`values="571;0;571"` - Animation on the path from 571px to zero and back

If I correctly understood the author of the question, animation is needed not for the path line, but for filling the whole figure formed by `path` with the color.

When the path is not closed, it would be easy to do this - increase the thickness of the line to the desired value and use the animation `stroke-dashoffset`

To solve these contradictions, you can use this technique: open our code in a vector editor and draw an additional curve that goes in the middle of the figure.
[image]

And this line will be animated. To start the animation, move the cursor.

```html
<svg id="svg2" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="420" height="180" viewBox="-50 550 372 80.4"  version="1.1">
  <path d="m18.9 529.4c1.1 2.2 1.7 4.6 1.7 7.1 0 2.4-0.6 4.8-1.7 6.9l36.9 0c17.1 0 11.1 14.8 13.5 34.9 7.3 27.3 35.9 38.1 62.6 41.7-1.5-2.4-4.3-7.9-4.3-10.9 0-3.1 0.9-5.7 2.7-8.3-23.3-1.1-29.9-7.3-39.3-22.3-4.8-11.4 5.7-49.2-28.7-49.2z"  
  style="fill:#F8F3EF;stroke-width:1; stroke:none;" />
     
  <path style="stroke-dasharray:152;stroke-dashoffset:152; fill:none;stroke-width:2;stroke:yellowgreen;"
  d="m20.8 535.9c24.9 2.5 55.9-6.4 57.2 15.4 3.5 19.3-1.6 31.7 14 45.2 21.1 17.5 35.4 13 35.4 13">
  <animate id="dash" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="152;0" begin="svg2.mouseover" restart="whenNotActive" dur="3s"    fill="freeze" repeatCount="1">
  </animate>

 </path>
</svg>
```

Next, increase the thickness of the line - `stroke-width: 20;` and get the desired result:

```html
<svg id="svg2" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="420" height="180" viewBox="-50 550 372 80.4"  version="1.1">
    
  <path d="m18.9 529.4c1.1 2.2 1.7 4.6 1.7 7.1 0 2.4-0.6 4.8-1.7 6.9l36.9 0c17.1 0 11.1 14.8 13.5 34.9 7.3 27.3 35.9 38.1 62.6 41.7-1.5-2.4-4.3-7.9-4.3-10.9 0-3.1 0.9-5.7 2.7-8.3-23.3-1.1-29.9-7.3-39.3-22.3-4.8-11.4 5.7-49.2-28.7-49.2z"  
  style="fill:#F8F3EF;stroke-width:1; stroke:none;" />
  
    
  <path style="stroke-dasharray:152;stroke-dashoffset:152; fill:none;stroke-width:20;stroke:yellowgreen;"
  d="m20.8 535.9c24.9 2.5 55.9-6.4 57.2 15.4 3.5 19.3-1.6 31.7 14 45.2 21.1 17.5 35.4 13 35.4 13">
  <animate id="dash" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="152;0" begin="svg2.mouseover" restart="whenNotActive" dur="3s"    fill="freeze" repeatCount="1">
  </animate>

 </path>
</svg>
```

### Solution using `filter`

The idea of a solution is initiated - [SVG Filter tag on hover @Holger Will](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41143067/7394871)

Animation of filling the path is achieved by changing the attribute of the filter `dx` - offset along the X axis.

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 width="420" height="180" viewBox="-50 540 372 80.4">
   <defs>
    <filter id="violet-fill" x="0%" y="0%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#F8F3EF" />
      <feOffset dx="0">
        <animate id="anim" attributeName="dx" values="0;115;0" dur="5s" begin="path1.mouseover" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze"/> 
      </feOffset>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <style>
  path {
  filter: url(#violet-fill);
}
  </style>
  <path id="path1" d="m18.9 529.4c1.1 2.2 1.7 4.6 1.7 7.1 0 2.4-0.6 4.8-1.7 6.9l36.9 0c17.1 0 11.1 14.8 13.5 34.9 7.3 27.3 35.9 38.1 62.6 41.7-1.5-2.4-4.3-7.9-4.3-10.9 0-3.1 0.9-5.7 2.7-8.3-23.3-1.1-29.9-7.3-39.3-22.3-4.8-11.4 5.7-49.2-28.7-49.2z"  
  style=" stroke:#4B0082; fill:#F8F3EF;"/>
</svg>
```

**The second solution with the help of animation `filter`**

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 width="420" height="180" viewBox="-50 540 372 80.4">
   <defs>
    <filter id="violet-fill" x="0%" y="0%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#ded9d5" />
      <feOffset dx="0">
        <animate id="anim" attributeName="dx" values="0;115;0" dur="5s" begin="path1.mouseover" restart="whenNotActive" fill="freeze"/> 
      </feOffset>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <style>
  path {
  filter: url(#violet-fill);
}
  </style>
  <path id="path1" d="m18.9 529.4c1.1 2.2 1.7 4.6 1.7 7.1 0 2.4-0.6 4.8-1.7 6.9l36.9 0c17.1 0 11.1 14.8 13.5 34.9 7.3 27.3 35.9 38.1 62.6 41.7-1.5-2.4-4.3-7.9-4.3-10.9 0-3.1 0.9-5.7 2.7-8.3-23.3-1.1-29.9-7.3-39.3-22.3-4.8-11.4 5.7-49.2-28.7-49.2z"  
  style=" stroke-width:1; stroke:violet;   fill:#4B0082;"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add a class instead of an ID and use CSS ":hover" on the class.

Or you can have both.

This is a great page for interactive svg. 
[Mouseover effects in SVGs](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/data-visualisation/mouseover-effects-svgs)

Example code, had to remove the hard coded styles in the svg for the css to take effect.

```css
.effective{
fill:red;
}

.effective:hover{
fill:black;
 transition: fill 2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<svg width="210mm" height="450mm" viewBox="0 0 744.09449 159.44881">
<path  d="m 18.929688,529.44141 c 1.140051,2.17164 1.739409,4.60197 1.74414,7.07226 -0.0033,2.41521 -0.575072,4.79339 -1.666016,6.92969 l 36.876954,0 c 17.101683,0 11.124297,14.78094 13.525192,34.92207 7.304679,27.32129 35.935342,38.13518 62.612922,41.73111 -1.5457,-2.42739 -4.33484,-7.94712 -4.33733,-10.8524 0.005,-3.11453 0.90166,-5.74434 2.66254,-8.27277 -23.30774,-1.1068 -29.8766,-7.34118 -39.33413,-22.29658 -4.829034,-11.35821 5.68082,-49.23338 -28.703413,-49.23338 z" transform="translate(0.5714286,1.42857)" class="effective" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I cant open this link can you provide me some other

Comment: Is this the kind of transition you wanted?

Comment: i want the color to flow as water in a pipe

Comment: If you want it to follow the pipe I would use an algorithm to take the points, and a start point, which follows the pipe using a space filling tree and than randomly flow opaque circles along until it fills and combine that with a transition like that one I used towards the end.

Are you trying to animate a water pipe?

The only other thing I can think of, is that you could use a clipping mask, but that would not look like water, just kind of.

Comment: can you give me a sample of it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143488/discussion-between-ram-and-chris).